# Comparação no "if" não cai onde deveria

Tags: c, string

Qual erro no meu código? Pois independentemente da resposta, o resultado é o do `else`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{               //variaveis
  char sigla[3];
  //programa
  printf ("Entre com a sigla do seu estado:");
  scanf ("%s", &sigla);
  if ((sigla == "RJ") || (sigla == "rj"))
    {
      printf ("\nCarioca!");
    }
  else if ((sigla == "SP") || (sigla == "sp"))
    {
      printf ("\nPaulista");
    }
  else if ((sigla == "MG") || (sigla == "mg"))
    {
      printf ("\nMineiro!");
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("\nOutros Estados!");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Tem dois problemas no código. 1) está usando `&` em algo que já é um endereço de memória. Quando tem um *array*, já tem o que o `scanf()` espera. 2) Você está comparando *strings* como se fossem caracteres. A forma corrente é comprar todos os caracteres do *array*. Para isto existe uma função pronta no `string.h` chama [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char sigla[3];
    printf("Entre com a sigla do seu estado:");
    scanf("%s", sigla);
    if (strcmp(sigla, "RJ") == 0 || strcmp(sigla, "rj") == 0) printf ("\nCarioca!");
    else if (strcmp(sigla, "SP") == 0 || strcmp(sigla, "sp") == 0) printf ("\nPaulista");
    else if (strcmp(sigla, "MG") == 0 || strcmp(sigla, "mg") == 0) printf ("\nMineiro!");
    else printf ("\nOutros Estados!");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2lAwfo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/msuyiufy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ReadindAndComparing.c).